# Graphql result does not populate result in associated Type using mongoose

Tags: mongoose, graphql

I have trying to create schemas in Mongoose with ObjectId reference and being able to query them via GraphQL using Apollo Server

I have defined a very basic Book and Author ObjectId ref in mongoose like this

```
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema.Types;
const AuthorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
});

const BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  author: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Author' }]
});
```

And having a graphql schema like this

```
  type Author {
    id: ID!
    name: String
  }

  type Book {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    author: Author
  }

  type Query {
    authors: [Author]
    author(id: ID!): Author
    books: [Book]
    book(id: ID!): Book
  }

  input AddAuthorInput {
    name: String!
  }

  input AddBookInput {
    name: String!
    author: ID!
  }

  type Mutation {
    addAuthor(input: AddAuthorInput): Author
    addBook(input: AddBookInput): Book
  }
```

The mutation section in resolver for addBook and book query is like this

```
    addBook: async (_, args) => {
      try {
        const {
          input
        } = args;
        return Book.create(input);
      } catch (e) {
        return e.message
      }
    }

      book: async (_, args) => {
        const { id } = args;
        const result = await Book.findById(id).populate('author').exec();

        console.warn('====== Book query result ======');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
        console.warn('====== End Book query result ======');

        return result;
```

When I query with this

```
query book {
  book(id: "xxxxxxx") {
    id
    name
    author {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

I get null in *author.name* while I can see from the console output that the .populate() was able to get correct result from Authors collection.

This [repo](https://github.com/rtao/graphql-schema-test) includes the sample code I have created

Comment: You saved my day with your question <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mongoose schema is set up to return multiple authors per book:

```
author: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Author' }]
```

If it should be just the one author, then just do:

```
author: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Author' }
```

You cannot return an array where GraphQL is expecting a single object and vice versa. If you wanted to keep your mongoose schema the same, you'd need to change the type returned by the `author` field to a `List` of `Authors`:

```
author: [Author]
```

Comment: You are right, and actually it was a mistake of setting up as array of Authors in mongoose schema

Comment: Hi! i have a little question: What happen if i need to get the author's id too?